# AWS SES Reply To Previous Email

Tags: email, amazon-web-services

Is it possible to reply to an email that I previously sent the user using AWS SES? I don't see anything within the documentation that would accomplish this.

So I want to:

(1) Send email to email address X

(2) Reply to email thread from (1)

Comment: You want smtg similar to a "Sent" box that you could find the original sent msg and reply to the original destination, is that it?

Comment: When I send, I get a message id. I'm hoping to be able to add an email reply on top of that email with that message id. I don't need to look up the previous emails, I can store them myself.

Comment: I think it will not be possible, as a reply is nothing more than a new message that email clients decide to group by some criteria (eg: title and sender). You can try to send a new email with "RE:" before the original title and test if your most common clientes (corporate email, gmail, outlook, etc.) group as you expect.

Comment: Thank you sir. I sent multiple with the same subject and they counted as the same email thread

Comment: I posted as an answer, if u dont mind to accept it ;)

Comment: Did you have any luck with this @AlexYurkowski? Am facing the same issue myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it will not be possible, as a reply is nothing more than a new message that email clients decide to group by some criteria (eg: title and sender). You can try to send a new email with "RE:" before the original title and test if your most common clientes (corporate email, gmail, outlook, etc.) group as you expect.

Comment: This is what ended up working for me, adding the "RE: " prefix for the subject. It's working in polymail, gmail, doesn't work in the safari mail client but i think that's good enough for now for my use case.

Comment: Note that in 2019 gmail changed how they group emails for threading, you will need to supply "References" header field. See https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2019/03/threading-changes-in-gmail-conversation-view.html

Answer (score 8):

With more complicated mailing schemes, filling the "References" and "In-Reply-To" headers of the proceeding message with the "Message-ID" generated by SES for the first message can nudge email clients to keep both messages in the same thread.

For instance, my use case was Alice referring a client to Bob. First, I wanted to send a message from Alice to Bob with the client's info (not seen by the client); then a message to the client, from Alice, CC'ing Bob, introducing the client and Bob.

Comment: When I send an email from ses, I get in response a message-id like - 010001760453b964-806e8d2d-9568-4e48-8d42-bca433a2656e-000000. I have trying sending "In-Reply-To" and "References" as above message-id and then appending @email.amazonses.com but it does not works. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: @SumitJangra I recently got this to work, make sure that your message-id is surrounded by "<" and ">" for the references and in-reply-to header fields, there is an example of what this should look like on https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2019/03/threading-changes-in-gmail-conversation-view.html

Comment: Did it work for only gmail or outlook too. For me, it was working already in gmail but not in outlook. Still I’ll give it a try and update here.

Comment: @SumitJangra, Did it end up working for you?

Answer (score -1):

Using the same subject counts as a reply within gmail.

Comment: Gmail does not group messages for me despite the subject being the same :(

Comment: You will also need to set the References header field, see https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2019/03/threading-changes-in-gmail-conversation-view.html