# How do I create an email thread when using AWS-SES?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I tried to first go through documentation and aws forums but not able to find any solution. [This](https://meta.discourse.org/t/emails-are-not-threaded-in-outlook-2013/16501) is one big discussion regarding threading in outlook but gives no solution. i am hoping it to be a fairly simple thing but since I am new to aws-ses, its getting hard to find a good solution for this.

Comment: Please have you found a solution to this?

Comment: Yes,you just need to send 2 extra headers 'In-Reply-To' and 'References' and the value of these 2 headers would be <message-id of last email to which you want to create a thread +"@email.amazonses.com>". Dont forget '<' & '>'. Eg. "<7bvsjdfhksbdkf896234bhksbdfbbhiosdf@email.amazonses.com>

Comment: thanks, but what algorithm did you use in threading them

Comment: No algorithm. You just need to pass these 2 extra headers and the mail would be send automatically in a thread.

Comment: For anyone having issues - the @email.amazonses.com was not working for me. I checked the email headers and the original message id had `us-west-2.amazonses.com` instead.

Comment: hey @bumbur, im guessing that us-west-2 was your region?

Comment: im too facing this error, anyone figured out how to attach the headers on ses?

Comment: @LakinduHewawasam You need to use the Raw email option, sendRawEmail in SES or as Raw property of Content for SESv2

Comment: Hey @RyanWolton, I tried this approach. It was too big of a hassle for me. There were tons of stuff to code for the same feature.  Instead I wrapped SES using `node mailer` and used it to implement threading. Works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Just need to send 2 extra headers 'In-Reply-To' and 'References' and the value of these 2 headers would be <message-id of last email to which you want to create a thread +"@email.amazonses.com>". Dont forget '<' & '>'. Eg. "7bvsjdfhksbdkf896234bhksbdfbbhiosdf@email.amazonses.com

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished it using the code below. I'm using pythn boto3 sdk for aws.

```
    message_handler = "exampleId"
    ses_client.send_email(
        Source=EMAIL_SENDER,
        Destination={
            "ToAddresses": EMAIL_RECEPIENTS,
        },
        Message={
            "Subject": {"Data": f"Test Subject - {message_handler}"},
            "Body": {
                "Html": {"Data": html_body},
            },
        },
        Tags=[{"Name": "CustomThreadID", "Value": message_handler}],
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the id to the headers didn't work for me in Gmail. I followed [this answer instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42659858/4083045) adding `RE: {original subject}` to the subject line - this worked.